# count function is not giving correct total count in soql query

Tags: soql, count

I am using below query to count the records based on the status field and grouping it's using one more picklist field. i am getting correct count respective to the individual picklist field but the total count is less. if we count the individual row count it comes 29 but in result its showing 26. can anyone please help me.

Please find the query and screenshot of result below:

```
SELECT Picklist__c, Count(Status) countOfStatus FROM Case WHERE (CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)= 4 AND CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate)= 2017 AND Status IN ('New','New Progress')) OR (CALENDAR_MONTH(ClosedDate)= 4 AND CALENDAR_YEAR(ClosedDate)= 2017 AND Status IN ('Solved','Successful')) GROUP BY Picklist__c
```

[image]

Comment: may be those 3 records not satisfying these conditions `(CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)= 4 AND CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate)= 2017 AND Status IN ('New','New Progress')) OR (CALENDAR_MONTH(ClosedDate)= 4 AND CALENDAR_YEAR(ClosedDate)= 2017 AND Status IN ('Solved','Successful'))`

Comment: You should show both queries...